# Convert a for loop into a while loop in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

The program I wrote by using 'for loop' is correct and passed all the testcases,however, when I transfer 'for loop' to 'while loop',an 'IndexError' occurred,I wonder what are the problems in my program which using 'while loop'.

```
nums = []
remainders=[]
while True:
    num=int(input('Number: '))
    if num==0:        
        break
    nums.append(num)    
if len(nums)==0:
    print('No integers were entered')
    exit()
a=0
while a<len(nums):
    num=nums[a]
    remainder=num%10
    remainders.append(remainder)
    a+=1
index=remainders.index(max(remainders))
count=0   
for i in remainders:
    if i > remainder:
        remainder=i
        count=0
    if i ==remainder:
        count+=1
if count ==1:
    print('The most interesting integer was: {}'.format(nums[index]))  
elif count>1 and count<len(nums):
    print('Two or more integers are the most interesting')
else:
    print('All integers have the same remainder')
```

That's the program I wrote by using for loop, this answer is correct

```
nums = []
remainders=[]
while True:
    num=int(input('Number: '))
    if num==0:        
        break
    nums.append(num)    
if len(nums)==0:
    print('No integers were entered')
    exit()
a=0
while a<len(nums):
    num=nums[a]
    remainder=num%10
    remainders.append(remainder)
    a+=1
index=remainders.index(max(remainders))
count=0   
k=0
while k<len(remainders):
    remainder=remainders[k]
    if remainders[k]>remainder:
        remainder=remainders[k]
        count=0
    k+=1    
    if remainders[k]==remainder:
        count+=1
    k+=1    
if count ==1:
    print('The most interesting integer was: {}'.format(nums[index]))  
elif count>1 and count<len(nums):
    print('Two or more integers are the most interesting')
else:
    print('All integers have the same remainder')
```

This answer is incorrect because the second while loop have some problems

```
actual:
Number: 4
Number: 20
Number: 9
Number: 3
Number: 5
Number: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numbers.py", line 26, in <module>
    if remainders[k]==remainder:
IndexError: list index out of range
expected:
Number: 4
Number: 20
Number: 9
Number: 3
Number: 5
Number: 0
The most interesting integer was: 9
```

Comment: I think you need to re-check your question title.

Comment: How do you decide the most interesting integer ?

Comment: I just have a question about what are the problems in the second 'while loop' of my second program,what are the problems of the conversion

Comment: the most intereting integer is the integer that has the largest remainder after divided by 10

Comment: Well the logic you are trying to do here also matters @Eric Please update the question with it

Comment: `remainder=remainders[k]; \\ 
    if remainders[k]>remainder:` This looks a bit off in your while-loop attempt (always evals to False).

Comment: @TrebledJ So how to transfer the 'for loop' in first program to 'while loop'?

Comment: You are incrementing k twice, as well as your `remainder=remainders[k]` is causing an issue, check my answer below @Eric

Comment: @davedwards, Oh, I found that, already updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues in your code

- You are doing `k+=1` twice, which is causing the `list index out of range` error, do it only once
- When you do `remainder=remainders[k] if remainders[k]>remainder`, this will always evaluate to False, remove the line `remainder=remainders[k]`

Keeping this in mind, the following while loop should work

```
while k<len(remainders):
    if remainders[k]>remainder:
        remainder=remainders[k]
        count=0
    if remainder==remainders[k]:
        count+=1
    #Increment only once
    k+=1
```

Comment: Thank you, however, when I change my incorrect while loop to this one,it just pass 8 of 12 testcases,when I changed the 'r' to remainder, all the testcases passed

Comment: what test cases are you talking about? I just ensured that the code runs for the input you provided!

Comment: Also you have another `remainder` somewhere in your previous `while a<len(nums):` and being used in `if r>remainder:`which is coming up here, try to isolate those two variables! Maybe you can also refactor your code to better isolate the issues!

Comment: Yes,the code runs for the input I provided, however, if there are more than one number have the largest remainder after divided by 10, the expected output should be 'Two or more integers are the most interesting'

Comment: Updated the loop! Now it should work for all cases @Eric